# How can I prove this version of tube lemma for Tychonoff theorem?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am trying to prove this version of tube lemma for the Tychonoff theorem.

Lemma. Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a collection of basis elements for the topology of the product space $X \times Y$ , such that no finite subcollection of $\mathscr{A}$ covers $X \times Y$ . If X is compact, there is a point $x$ in X such that no finite subcollection of A covers the slice ${x} \times Y$ .

For solutions on the Internet, they claim that we can choose **finitely many** open sets of the form $U \times V$.
(https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/math/topo/soln09.pdf, 06-(a))

But I'm not sure that how can we choose the basis of the form like that. Although we know that $\mathscr{A}$ is a collection of basis element, It doesn't have to be a form of open boxes.

If anyone know that how can we choose such open boxes for arbitrary forms of bases?

Comment: This is because they **assume** (to get a contradiction!) that we can choose finitely many such base elements for *every* $x$. It's part of a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for answering. Now I understand. For arbitrary finite Ax, the box π1(A) * π2(A) is a canonical box which finitely covers the slice. So, it doesn't really matter either way. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, on the contrary, that for each $x\in X$ there is a finite $\mathscr{A}_x\subseteq\mathscr{A}$ that covers the slice $\{x\}\times Y$. Then there are an $n_x\in\Bbb Z^+$, open nbhds $U_k(x)$ in $X$ for $k=1,\ldots,n_x$, and open sets $V_k(x)$ in $Y$ for $k=1,\ldots,n_x$ such that

$$\mathscr{A}_x=\{U_k(x)\times V_k(x):k=1,\ldots,n_x\}\;.$$

For each $x\in X$ let

$$W(x)=\bigcap_{k=1}^nU_k(x)\;.$$

- Verify that $W(x)$ is an open nbhd of $x$.

For $x\in X$ let

$$\mathscr{A}_x'=\{W(x)\times V_k(x):k=1,\ldots,n_x\}\;.$$

- Verify that $\mathscr{A}_x'$ is an open cover of $\{x\}\times Y$.

Let $\mathscr{W}=\{W(x):x\in X\}$.

- Use compactness of $X$ to get a finite $\mathscr{W}_0=\{W(x_1),\ldots,W(x_m)\}\subseteq\mathscr{W}$ covering $X$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$.
- Then show that $\bigcup_{k=1}^m\mathscr{A}_{x_k}$ is a finite subfamily of $\mathscr{A}$ covering $X\times Y$, thereby getting the desired contradiction.

Comment: My question is this : 
How did you choose $\mathscr{A}_x=\{U_k(x)\times V_k(x):k=1,\ldots,n_x\}$? If the form of the bases $\mathscr{A}$ is not a box U x V, I think there may not exist finitely many box basis elements Uk x Vk.

for example, in R^2, it can be a diamond shape or etc... for all other shapes of bases, how can we assure that there are finitely many elements of box basis elements?

Comment: @artes75 the box basic elements (as you call them) **are** the basic elements that the statement is talking about. They are the standard, canonical base elements for the product, and if a theorem talks about basic elements of the product, this is what they mean. Unless there is a predefined already defined alternative base for a particular case, but this does not seem the case here.

Comment: @artes75 if the bases are arbitrary but for the product topology, we can always choose canonical base elements inside it anyway (or we would not induce the product topology!). So it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you. Um... For the "either way", For an arbitrary two different bases $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$, I know that any element of $\mathscr{A}$ can be expressed by union of $\mathscr{B}$'s elements. But I still don't understand why there should be "finitely" many box elements inside an arbitrary basis element, which covers the slice x * Y. You mentioned that (or we would not induce the product topology), could you please explain some more details?